# Displaying the execution script for a Java application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, execution

is there a way to display, in Eclipse, the full command line that is used to execute a java application?
I am using Juno.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean what actual binary is running your java application? The actual command as it would be seen on the command line for when you run the Java application through Eclipse?  Can you be a bit more specific as to what you are looking for.

Comment: I've edited the question. I'd need to see the full command line Eclipse uses to execute a java application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but if you're looking for the full command line of the current execution, I'm not aware of a place you can see that in Eclipse. If you are on Windows though, I'd recommend SysInternals (now Microsoft) [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). Below is an example of the properties of a process I started in Debug mode from Eclipse.

[image: Process Explorer process properties]

Comment: Linux? try `ps -ef | grep java`

Comment: Domenic D.: Thanks, but if you read my question well I am asking for a way to see that in Eclipse...